# How do I call a javscript function when content is edited in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, highlight.js

I have a website that I am making that uses the highlight.js script. It's basically a syntax highlighting javascript code that highlights all `<code>` blocks. I have a `<code contenteditable>` block. I wanted to make it so that the syntax highlighting is realtime, or in other words, call the higlight function whenever the content is edited. How can I achieve this?

Django HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'tokyo-night-dark.min.css' %}">
<div class="main">
<pre><code contenteditable>{{code}}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Function to execute:

```
<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
```

Comment: I highly recommend to read the [highlight.js documentation](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) that explains perfectly fine how to use it.

Comment: I did read it, and I know I have to use the code from the 'Custom Usage' section with an event listener. I guess what I was looking for was how do I get an event from a content editable which I could use, and I just found an answer for that on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this to your **`HTML`**

Link the library, and call `highlightAll`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="/path/to/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
```

*This should automatically highlight code inside of `<pre><code>` tags*

If the above steps didn't work you could do it manually using the class attribute:

```
<pre><code class="language-html">...</code></pre>
```

Comment: I read the documentation, all of these lines are present in my code. When I load the page, whatever is default in the code block gets highlighted, but when I edit it it doesn't highlight the new text.